# Absolute value of lubridate periods

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am trying to determine the absolute number of days between two dates using lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- data.frame(
  time1 = date(c("2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01")),
  time2 = date(c("2011-01-02", "2011-12-31", "2013-01-01"))
)

dates$diff <- days(dates$time1 - dates$time2)
```

```
dates$diff
```

```
[1] "-1d 0H 0M 0S" "1d 0H 0M 0S"  "0S"
```

```
abs(dates$diff)
```

```
[1] "-1d 0H 0M 0S" "1d 0H 0M 0S"  "0S"
```

I would have expected all of the values to be positive. Furthermore, `min` and `max` do not return the smallest and largest values.

```
min(dates$diff)
```

```
[1] 0
```

```
max(dates$diff)
```

```
[1] 0
```

Why do these functions behave differently on `lubridate` periods than on numeric/integer objects?

Comment: `dates$diff <- abs(day(days(dates$time1 - dates$time2)))` This works for you?

Comment: Functions seem to be redundant, why not just `dates$diff <- dates$time1 - dates$time2`? The output is days, and `abs, min, max` will work.

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you - that does solve my specific problem, as does the function `time_length()`, but it doesn't answer my question about the `period` class in `lubridate`, since your solution creates a `difftime` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that `period` class objects from lubridate are not simple numeric objects. They are S4 objects. Their main data member is the numeric vector of *seconds*, with the minutes, hours, days and years all stored as *attributes*. When you try to apply mathematical operators on `period` objects, the operators don't apply to the attributes, only to the main numerical vector, which is the seconds part.

We can see this if we create a `period` of -1 seconds:

```r
library(lubridate)

p <- as.period(diff(as.POSIXct(c("2020-09-24 21:00:01", "2020-09-24 21:00:00"))))

p
#> [1] "-1S"

abs(p)
#> [1] "1S"
```

Now let us examine our object's attributes:

```r
attributes(p)
#> $year
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $month
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $day
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $hour
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $minute
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "Period"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "lubridate"
```

With S4 objects, you need to define what functions like `abs` and `min` will do by writing the "Math" and "Summary" group generics. However, these have not been defined for class "period", so they instead are called on the main data vector (which is just the vector of seconds). The `Ops` group generic *has* been defined though, which us why you can do things like `dates$diff / 2` and get a sensible answer.

Why have they not been defined? That's one for the authors to answer. In the meantime, you could get the functionality you want by making `abs` an S3 method and specifically writing an `abs.period` method, like this:

```
abs         <- function(x) UseMethod("abs")
abs.default <- function(x) base::abs(x)
abs.Period  <- function(out) 
{
   new("Period", abs(out$second), 
       year = abs(out$year), 
       month = abs(out$month), 
       day = abs(out$day), hour = abs(out$hour), 
       minute = abs(out$minute))
}
```

Which would give your expected behaviour:

```r
dates <- data.frame(
  time1 = date(c("2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01")),
  time2 = date(c("2011-01-02", "2011-12-31", "2013-01-01"))
)

dates$diff <- days(dates$time1 - dates$time2)

abs(dates$diff)
#> [1] "1d 0H 0M 0S" "1d 0H 0M 0S" "0S"
```

However, this is probably not a great idea. Best to work with difftimes for arithmetic and and convert to periods if needed.

I hope that clarifies things a bit.